# Initialize get_option() from wordpress plugin using hooks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I am currently developing a custom theme option plugin. So if form is submitted and it has values they will be stored in wp_options with row name "wp_so_options"

```
if( isset( $_POST['wp_so_submitted'])){
     $hidden_field =esc_html( $_POST['wp_so_submitted'] );
     if($hidden_field == 'Y'){

       $wp_so_twitter_url = $_POST['wp_so_twitter_url'];
       $wp_so_facebook_url = $_POST['wp_so_facebook_url'];
       $options['wp_so_twitter_url'] = $wp_so_twitter_url;
       $options['wp_so_facebook_url'] = $wp_so_facebook_url;

       update_option('wp_so_options',$options);
     }
   }
```

Now I am retrieving them in plugin files using

```
$options = get_option('wp_so_options');
```

and echo works perfectly

```
  echo $options['wp_so_twitter_url'];
```

Now I want to use these values in wordpress theme.

But unless I initialize the options in header/index.php I am not able to retrieve them

```
 $options = get_option('wp_so_options');
```

Is there any way using hook I can initialize the above from plugin files to theme so I can use without initializing the same in theme file. What I am looking to do is activate the plugin and call these fields to pages using short coded without touching php. So end user need not touch php can use short coded.

I tried this but did not work:

```
function global_options_so() {
global $options;
$options = get_option('wp_so_options');
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'global_options_so' );
```

Thanks in advance.